# SpEL (Spring) syntax for default value when property non-existant or equal to 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I'm trying to set an Integer property to a default value of 1 if it either does not exist or if its current value is 0 and I can't for the life of me get the 0 comparison to work properly.

The original value (if set) will come in via the command line.

Here are the relevant line in my class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${${instance.procmultiplier} == 0 ? Integer.parseInt('1') : ${instance.procmultiplier}}")
    public Integer procMultiplier;
}
```

I have tried numerous variations of the @Value annotation and at one point, I swear it recognized the 0 value, and I can't get back to that state.  I was first trying to simply get it to recognize the 0 value and default to 1 and I was then going to try and insert a null-check.

Is there a way to do both all in the same annotation?  One idea I had was to split the null-check and 0-check into two different properties, basically have `procmultiplier=${instance.procmultiplier:1}` in a properties file and then change the annotation to `@Value("${${procmultiplier} == 0 ? Integer.parseInt('1') : ${procmultiplier}}")` but nothing I try works.

My command is: `mvn clean package && java -Dspring.profiles.active=json -Dinstance.procmultiplier=0 -jar target/MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

The property ends up just being equal to whatever I set it to on the command line.

Any ideas on how to check for both non-existent and 0 and default to 1 if either is true, otherwise set to whatever comes in via command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears my problem was using `${...}` instead of `#{...}`.  Here is my solution using two different properties:

bootstrap.properties

`procmultiplier=${instance.procmultiplier:1}`

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("#{${procmultiplier} == 0 ? 1 : ${procmultiplier}}")
    public Integer procMultiplier;
}
```

Command Line:
`mvn clean package && java -Dspring.profiles.active=json -Dinstance.procmultiplier=0 -jar target/MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Also allows for a missing `instance.procmultiplier` parameter.

I still don't know how to do it all in one shot with 1 property though...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language) you should try

```
@Value("#{someBean.someProperty != null ? someBean.someProperty : 'default'}")
private String ternary;
```

Comment: It's not a bean, it's a simple property.

Comment: Additionally, checking for 'null' is not the same as checking for existence.  If I leave the property off the command line, I get a Could not resolve placeholder error.

Comment: You also can add the `&& someBean.someProperty != 0` condition. And if you want you can give a default value in the application.properties for that value

Comment: It's still not a bean.  In order to resolve a property (as opposed to a bean field), you need ${...} inside.  Your answer is not correct, but did give me some much needed inspiration!

Comment: Actually that is also written in the post at '2. Operators' section. But my answer was half correct because of the #{...} thingy :D the other half is yours, so I gave you an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in xml:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="myClass" >
    <property name="myProp" value="#{systemProperties['a.b'] ?: '${a.b}'}"/>
</bean>
```

This will take from system properties if exist, otherwise from property file